# How to purchase multiple tickets in the Île-de-France Mobilités app for public transport in Paris

Tags: public-transport, france, applications, transportation, paris

I downloaded the [Île-de-France Mobilités](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.applidium.vianavigo&hl=fr) app for transport in Paris.

I will be traveling with my wife and her phone does not support [NFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-field_communication), so she can't purchase tickets with hers.

I want to purchase two tickets with my phone and validate them immediately. That's what I usually do when we travel, but the barriers' system in the stations where you have to scan your ticket to open the gate is confusing me.

So when I select two tickets and do the payment, do they get validated immediately and then I just pass my phone on the scanner and the gate will open for me then I pass my phone to my wife and she will scan the second ticket purchased and the gate will be open for her?

It did not seem the correct way for me.
What is the right way?

I was chatting with the support team using a translator and they didn't understand what I meant.

[image]

Comment: I don't have the answer, but the assumption that it would validate two tickets at the same time is very likely not correct

Comment: you can just buy physical tickets at most stations

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot do this.

As the General Terms and Conditions state:

> 4.3.          Il est impossible de valider plusieurs tickets t+ d’un même support sans contact pour permettre le voyage de plusieurs
> personnes sur un même trajet.

See *[Conditions générales de vente et d'utilisation (CGVU) du ticket T+ sur support sans contact](https://www.iledefrance-mobilites.fr/cgvu-ticket-t-sans-contact)*.

Translation: It is not possible to validate multiple t+ tickets on the same contact-less carrier to permit multiple persons to travel the same route.

This information doesn't seem to appear in the plain text language on the RATP (metro) website, but it is stated on the [Transilien (suburband trains) site](https://www.transilien.com/en/page-tarifs/nfc):

> Please note, the service does not allow several people to travel simultaneously. 1 phone = 1 traveler, like for a Navigo card.

Comment: Thank you for your help. We will buy then the navigo easy travel card

Comment: @DevTN Note that once you have a Navigo easy, you can also use your phone to load tickets on it, no need to do it at the station.